# Import table from SQlite to Ms Access vba

Tags: vba, sqlite, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2016

I have an Access application with a backend datbase in sqlite, and now I want to import tables from sqlite's database to access via VBA, I tried this code :

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database", "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:\MyDatabse.db", acTable, "tblCustomer", "tblCustomer"
```

And also I tried this way to import database table :

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim strConn As String
Dim ODBCTableName As String
Dim AccessTableName As String

Set db = CurrentDb()

ODBCTableName = "tblCustomer"
AccessTableName = "tblCustomer"

strConn = "Driver={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};Database=C:\MyDatabse.db;"

Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef(AccessTableName)

tdf.SourceTableName = ODBCTableName
tdf.Connect = strConn

db.TableDefs.Append tdf
```

But the two ways give this error after runing :

[image: sqlite]

Comment: Have you installed the SQLite3 ODBC Driver that matches the bitness of your Office installation?

Comment: No, I haven't, but "SQLite3 ODBC Driver" is in driver lists of access and manually I'm import ing tables with this item.